# Fast R-CNN: do we extract region proposals from a single feature map?

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I'm trying to understand the evolution in object detection algorithms. 
As reference I'm using Andrej Karpathy slides of lecture 8 [here the slides](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2016/winter1516_lecture8.pdf).

I think I understood why we go from R-CNN to Fast R-CNN: instead of running each (warped) proposed region into a Convnet we run the original image into a Convnet and then we extract the region proposals from the feature map (or do we? I also wonder how initial RoI are mapped to feature maps):

[image]

**Here lie my doubts**: a single feature map? How do we get from many feature maps to a single one? Or is it just a definition misunderstanding, where with feature map we are considering a tensor with depth equal to the number of 2d feature maps exiting from the convolutional layers?

*Context*: Usually I have many feature maps as output of a convolutional network, which then I transform into a fully connected layer to do classification.
To me a feature map is the output of a convolution (+ relu + pooling) operation, so I have one feature map for each convolutional filter (consider for my understanding a single channel image so that we can refer just to 2d convolution).

Thank you for your help